# ElasticSearch: how min_doc_count affects performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

Why is the time taken of this:

```
"aggs": {
            "Condition": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "color",
                    "size": 10,
                    "min_doc_count": 1
                }
          }
```

is drastically faster than this:

```
    "aggs": {
            "Condition": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "color",
                    "size": 10,
                    "min_doc_count": 0
                }
          }
```

Even though they both return the same aggregation result to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html):

> Setting min_doc_count=0 will also return buckets for terms that didn’t match any hit. However, some of the returned terms which have a document count of zero might only belong to deleted documents or documents from other types, so there is no warranty that a match_all query would find a positive document count for those terms.

So it seems that if you have lots of deleted documents the performance would be worse because the aggregation would process a bigger amount of documents. Try to [optimize the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html) to see if the performance becomes similar.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to  @moliware answer from the [documentation excerpt](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

> Setting min_doc_count=0 will also return buckets for terms that didn’t
>   match any hit. However, some of the returned terms which have a
>   document count of zero might only belong to deleted documents or
>   documents from other types, so there is no warranty that a match_all
>   query would find a positive document count for those terms.

besides deleted documents with `min_doc_count=0` another significant caveat is that aggregation is not restricted to documents that match the parent query or restricted to the `types` .

See the below example:
Example:

1) Create test index

```
PUT  test
```

2) Insert documents of `type1` and `type3`

```
POST _bulk 
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"1"}}
{"condition":"good"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"2"}}
{"condition":"bad"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"3"}}
{"condition":"soso"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"4"}}
{"condition":"excellent"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"5"}}
{"condition":"bad"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"6"}}
{"condition":"bad"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"7"}}
{"condition":"excellent"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"type3","_id":"1"}}
{"condition":"unwell"}
```

3) Query all documents of `type1` without term `bad`:

```
POST test/type1/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": {
            "term": {
               "condition": "bad"
            }
         }
      }
   },
    "aggs": {
            "condition_value": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "condition",
                    "size": 10,
                    "min_doc_count": 0
                }
          }
    }

}
```

Response:

```
  "aggregations": {
      "condition_value": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "excellent",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "good",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "soso",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "bad",
               "doc_count": 0
            },
            {
               "key": "unwell",
               "doc_count": 0
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Note the documents of `type:type3` and `condition:bad` in the results.
Since the term aggregations are by default orderd by `doc_count` and the OP has `size:10` it may appear to not affect the overall result setting `size:0` would give a better picture. In short the number of terms used for generating the aggregation would be significantly larger with `min_doc_count:0`.